# Error mysqli_insert_id

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Using [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) I created following code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO inserir(nome) VALUES ('Stefanato');";
$listar = new consultar();
$listar->executa($query);

echo "New record has id: " . mysqli_insert_id($listar->$query);
```

I also used this answer for class connections: [Error mysqli_select_db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981180/error-mysqli-select-db)

But I keep getting this error:

> Warning: mysqli_insert_id () expects parameter exactly 1, 2 given in
>   /home/controle/public_html/demo/teste.php on line 9

How do I fix that?

Comment: What if you remove the dollar sign after `mysqli_insert_id($listar->`?

Comment: mysqli_insert_id($listar)

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois I did not understand matter of removing the symbol of the dollar. Just wanted to know what the last record ID

Comment: @Mihai I don't think `$listar` is the mysqli object due to `executa` instead of `execute`. `$listar` might be a wrapper class.

Comment: @Stefanato Just remove it and look what happens. Due to the extra dollar sign PHP might think you are passing two arguments.

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois I did like that echo "New record has id: " . mysqli_insert_id($listar); error Warning: mysqli_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in /home/controle/public_html/demo/teste.php on line 9
New record has id:

Comment: You might want to try `echo "New record has id: " . mysqli_insert_id($listar->query);`

Comment: @Mihai Right is right, show me, I'm trying!

Comment: @Mihai
Notice: Undefined property: consultar::$query in /home/controle/public_html/demo/teste.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/controle/public_html/demo/teste.php on line 9
New record has id:

Comment: Here URL: http://mypanel.com.br/demo/teste.php

Comment: @Mihai Can you help me?

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois Can you help me? You saw the error message?

Comment: What is your class `consultar`? Can you post the code (edit your question)?

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois Using this one --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981180/error-mysqli-select-db (This inserting, in the very last of the id register)

Comment: Pass `$consultar->bd->bancoDados` to `mysqli_insert_id` and define `$bancoDados` in your `conecta` class on  new line after `class conecta {` (`var $bancoDados;`)

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois Okay, but do not know which to put right, I'm trying! Before I wore only mysql_insert_id()

Comment: Try  `$listar->mysqli_insert_id();`

Comment: Oops, you need to pass `$listar->bd->bancoDados` to the function. `echo "New record has id: " . mysqli_insert_id($listar->bd->bancoDados); `.

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/controle/public_html/demo/teste.php on line 9

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/controle/public_html/demo/teste.php on line 11

Warning: mysqli_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/controle/public_html/demo/teste.php on line 11
New record has id:

Comment: Put `public $bancoDados;` on a new line after `class conecta {`

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois Could you show me?

Comment: Your posted link is working I can see any warning

Comment: @Charlotte Thank you, the script is working well now. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simple example for getting the id of last record created-

[Code is taken from here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_insert_id.asp)

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName,Age)
        VALUES ('Glenn','Quagmire',33)");

    // Print auto-generated id
    echo "New record has id: " . mysqli_insert_id($con);

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**Edit: Here is working code**

```
<?php
define("SERVIDOR_BD", "localhost");
define("USUARIO_BD", "usuario");
define("SENHA_BD", "senha");
define("BANCO_DE_DADOS", "dados");


class conecta {
    public $database_bancoDados = null;//1. New Added Field
    public $bancoDados = null;//2. New Added Field
    function conecta($servidor="", $bancoDeDados="", $usuario="", $senha=""){
        if (($servidor == "") && ($usuario == "") && ($senha == "") && ($bancoDeDados == "")){
            $this->bancoDados = mysqli_connect(SERVIDOR_BD, USUARIO_BD, SENHA_BD) or trigger_error(mysqli_error(),E_USER_ERROR);//3. Store in class variable
            $this->database_bancoDados = BANCO_DE_DADOS;//4. Store in class variable
        } else {
            $this->bancoDados = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha) or trigger_error(mysqli_error(),E_USER_ERROR);//5. Store in class variable
            $this->database_bancoDados = $bancoDeDados;//6. Store in class variable
        }
    }    
}

class consultar {

    var $bd;
    var $res;
    var $row;
    var $nrw;
    var $data;

    function executa($sql=""){
        if($sql==""){
            $this->res =  0; // Pointer result of the executed query
            $this->nrw =  0; // Line number the query returned, cruise control
            $this->row = -1; // Array of the current query line
        }
        // Connects to the database   
           $this->bd = new conecta();//7. Store in class variable
           $this->bd->conecta();//8. Store in class variable
           mysqli_select_db($this->bd->bancoDados, BANCO_DE_DADOS);//9. Change Here For parameter sequence
            $this->res = mysqli_query($this->bd->bancoDados, $sql); //10. Change here for parameter sequence

           $this->nrw = @mysqli_num_rows($this->res);

        $this->row = 0;
        if($this->nrw > 0)
            $this->dados();
    }

    function primeiro(){
        $this->row = 0;
        $this->dados();
    }

    function proximo(){
        $this->row = ($this->row<($this->nrw - 1)) ?
                        ++$this->row:($this->nrw - 1);
        $this->dados();
    }

    function anterior(){
        $this->row = ($this->row > 0) ? -- $this->row:0;
        $this->dados();
    }        

    function ultimo(){
        $this->row = $this->nrw-1;
        $this->dados();
    }

    function navega($linha){
        if($linha>=0 AND $linha<$this->nrw){
            $this->row = $linha;
            $this->dados();
        }
    }

    function dados(){
        mysqli_data_seek($this->res, $this->row);
        $this->data = mysqli_fetch_array($this->res);
    }
}

$query = "INSERT INTO inserir(uname) VALUES ('Stefanato');";
$listar = new consultar();
$listar->executa($query);

echo "New record has id: " . mysqli_insert_id($listar->bd->bancoDados);//11. Change Here for parameter
```

Comment: This might be a correct example, but this does not help OP to solve his problem as his case differs from the example.

Comment: The point to note is that `mysqli_insert_id()` takes the open connection parameter. To ensure it you can try `var_dump($listar->$query)` before `mysqli_insert_id($listar->$query)`.

Comment: @Kamal Singh Got it, I performed this procedure. Any idea where this missing?

Comment: I have attached complete code as per your references. I have marked the changes from 1 to 11 as comment, where I have added/modified the existing code.

Comment: @Kamal Thank you, the script is working well now. :-)